# textinput.py Sample code in Google Assistant SDK is not doing what I ask or answering questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk

I am using the google assistant sdk on a raspberry pi. I am trying to use the [textinput.py](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py) sample code to ask google assistant to play some music on my Google Home Mini (it is called 'Bedroom Speaker'). The problem is, when I enter text queries they don't do anything. I pasted an example below:

`: hey google, play music on bedroom speaker`

`<you> hey google, play music on bedroom speaker`

`: play music`

`<you> play music`

`<@assistant> Play Music. Google Play Music is a music and podcast streaming service and online music locker operated by Google, part of its Google Play line of services. The service was announced on May 10, 2011; after a six-month, invitation-only beta period, it was publicly launched on November 16, 2011. Wikipedia ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Music ).`

`:`

After asking the pi to play music on my Google Home Mini, nothing happens. When asking other questions like "Play Music" it just gives a wiki definition of Google Play Music. If I ask other normal questions like "What time is it?" there is no text response, but it reads out `<@assistant>`

Do you have any ideas on why it will not play music on my Home Mini? I have tested this command on my phone and it works; it does not work on my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing music is not supported in the Google Assistant SDK.